# Adjust height of UILabel dynamically using iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a label, which has been created using iOS Storyboard layout.

Contents of label, however, are dynamic and can change during run time.

How do I make sure that label's height gets adjusted based on the content in the label.

I tried:

Setting number of lines to 0

Setting `Editor -> Size to Fit Content`.

But they don't work. Text in label gets printed only in single line, and as a result of that some of text doesn't appear on the screen.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your number of line to 0 doesnt work because you already pinned its top or bottom or inside another fixed view thus it get fixed height, try remove either and try again

Comment: did you place it inside a UITableViewCell?

Comment: set pin to leading, top, trailing to your label and set aspect ration to label it will set size dynamically

Answer (score 11):

[image]
Try this way

Your lable **should be number of lines** to 0

give **height constraint** to lable and select height constraint then set **greater than equal**  , it will automatically adjust height based on content

Answer (score 1):

Please check your constraints. You can't set label's height constraint.If superview's height is fixed,you can't set top and bottom constraint at same time.Because it means you set the height constraint of label. So you can must fix label width and you can't fix label height.