# Auto Increament in Label Height in ios if Web-services data is more

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, constraints

By using this code will showing the value of Web-services,but I want to auto increase the height as more Data is coming .

`[cell.Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@",[detailsDict objectForKey:@"senderName"] ]];
cell.Label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.Label.numberOfLines = 3;`

Comment: are you trying with auto layout, if give number of line = 0, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471569/adjust-height-of-uilabel-dynamically-using-ios-storyboard/38472260#38472260

Comment: Yes ,if I remove Constraint then its not look good.. less data  only 1 row showing .. I want fix 2 row atleast and if more data is coming then auto increase

Comment: Check that link, you will get idea

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint to label
2. Put this two line in ViewDidLoad

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // standard tableViewCell height

   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
3. cell.Label.numberOfLines = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the height of label to two line and give label to constraint from four side.
top,
bottom,
left,
right.

then it works dynamically.

and also use

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = "Set height which is at design time of cell"

tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension